# Can we use classes in C++ AMP? And can we announce variables in GPU directly?

Tags: c++, class, memory, parallel-processing, gpu

I'm now working on a project to accelerate a intensive computing program with C++ AMP, but the programmer has used **classes**, which is friendly for the programmers, but seems rather unfriendly to AMP. Are classes supported in AMP?

Also, I wonder if I can directly announce variables in the **GPU memory**, since the simulation costs approximately 2.4GB memory, and will cost much time if transferred from global memory to GPU memory.

there is the class announcement

```
class SCM_MIMO_Fading

{

public:

    SCM_MIMO_Fading(int u = 2, int s = 2, int numFreq = 50);
    ~SCM_MIMO_Fading(void);
    void Refresh();
public:

    int NumTx;
    int NumRx;
    int NumOfFreqs;
    double * MatData;
    SCM_FreqFading * MatElements;
};
```

The main computing for the GPU is some multiplications of matrixs and Fast Fourier Transformation, note that the data are complex numbers, stressing heavy burden on the GPU.

Hope you can help me with this ;-)

Comment: Provide some piece of code to show what classes looks like, and what kind of computing your are doing with them!

Comment: Could you please help with this problem? I've provided some piece of code of the class, and described the computing process. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C++ expert but based on the information if found here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/12/19/restrict-amp-restrictions-part-0-of-n-introduction.aspx

The answer to your 1st question , " Are classes supported in AMP?", is

No you can't , only some fundamentals types are supported. For performance reason.

And for your 2nd question,  I also think it won't work. Based on the design of the AMP API , it's clearly not design for that, but you can read here http://www.anandtech.com/show/7118/windows-81-and-vs2013-bring-gpu-computing-updates-to-direct3d-and-c-amp-

"C++ AMP programs will also gain a shared memory feature on APUs/SoCs where the compiler and runtime will be able to eliminate extra data copies between CPU and GPU. This feature will also be available only on Windows 8."

Comment: Oh thank you, I have given up using classes in AMP, but apply some basic data types to do the math.